# how can I create ToInt32 method in System namespace?

Tags: c#, type-conversion, int

As you know, we can convert to string using Convert.ToString or ToString. I want to  make the same thing for integer, byte etc. Furthermore, I want to see this method for every object when I put dot. 
How should I write the method?

Comment: What is the converted integer value for *I like pie*?

Comment: Off-topic because well...you're just describing what you want without any visible attempt but, anyway, if you REALLY really want it...write extension methods for `Object` like `static int ToInt32(this object obj) => ...`. Of course don't forget to first check if object itself provides some conversion (`IConvertible`, possibly custom operators, maybe `TypeConverter`?). Why don't you simply use `Convert.ChangeType()`? In my humble opinion you will just pollute every type with mostly useless methods.

Comment: It would be very poor form to define an extension method on `object` in the `System` namespace. At least use a different namespace so you don't force everyone to clutter up their intellisense with your method.

Comment: Take a look at `int.Parse` or, much better still, `int.TryParse`.  The latter handles strings like @Plutonix's "I like pie" without throwing an exception

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for a extension method. just create a static class and a static method inside it like:

```
public static class Exts
{
     public static int ToInt32(this string x)
     {
          int result = 0;
          int.TryParse(x, out result);
          return result;
     }
}
```

of course my method is a sample and it just returns 0 for any string value that is not castable to int, however you may write any code, accept default value as argument, throw exception,...

Then you can use it like:

```
string a = "123";
int b = a.ToInt32();
int c = "321".ToInt32();
```

Comment: That's how you'd do it.  But, **_Don't do it_**.  If you do, you will regret it.

Comment: @Flydog57 don't do what?

Comment: why downvote? please comment the problem and do not just downvote

Comment: It's not my downvote.  Don't create a `ToInt32` extension method on `string`.  It will hide a little too much information.  Use `int.TryParse` (which with the latest version of C# that allows inline out variable declarations is much easier to use) and explicitly show what you want to do with parse failures.  If you add this to your code, you will regret it in the long run.  You don't have to believe me, but....

Comment: he wanted to do have this extension for all types, and string is one of them, and i have actually used tryparse

Comment: I'm not commenting on the validity of your solution.  It mostly answers his question (you can't extend `object` in an extension method anyway).  That's why I said "That's how you'd do it".  My "don't do it" is pointed at the OP.  I really think it's a bad idea.  Sorry if you thought I was throwing shade at your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Write a generic extension that converts any type to `Int32`:

```
public static class ObjectExt {
    public static int ToInt<T>(this T obj) => Convert.ToInt32(obj);
}
```